# multiple messages udp

Tags: java, android, udp

I'm trying to send multiple packets from android server to client, but the problem is that the code stops after 2 iterations only and then it exit with uncaught exception, so what am I doing wrong.
 can you help me please?

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.DatagramPacket;
import java.net.DatagramSocket;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.SocketException;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainTalker extends Activity 
{
private static DatagramSocket socket;
private static DatagramPacket packet;
private static Thread send;
private Button cl1;
private static EditText ed1;
private static String msg = "Message";
private static byte[] data = new byte[15];
//private static byte[] pktcount = new byte[10];
private static String TAG = "Sender UDP";
static int count=0;
static String[] output = new String[100] ;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_talker);

    ed1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msg);
    cl1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send);

    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(11001);
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Port Opened",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        System.out.println("Port Opened ");
        socket.setBroadcast(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: Port not opened");
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
    }

    cl1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            System.out.println("Button Clicked ");

            send = new sendthr();
            send.start();
        }
    });
}

private static class sendthr extends Thread {
    public void run()
    {
            System.out.println("Thread Started");

            String messg = ed1.getText().toString();
            System.out.println(messg);
            for (int i=0; i<=messg.length(); i+=10)
            {
                if(messg.length()>i+10)
                    output[i] = messg.substring(i,i+10);
                else
                    output[i]=messg.substring(i);
                count++;
                output[i+1] =count + ": " + output[i];
                System.out.println(output[i+1]);
            }
            output[0] = Integer.toString(count);
            System.out.println(count);
            if (messg == null)
                messg = msg;
            int i =0;
            while(i !=count)
            {
            data = output[i].getBytes();
            try
            { //Create packet with target host and target port
                packet = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length,InetAddress.getByName("192.168.8.17"), 11001);
                System.out.println("Packet Created");

            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: Packet Created");

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            try
            {
                System.out.println("Sending the packet  "+ msg);
                socket.send(packet);
                System.out.println("Packet sent");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: Packet Send");
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
            i++;
        }     
}
```

}
}

*this is the error messages I'm having:

```
11-22 15:58:59.381: W/dalvikvm(1223): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
11-22 15:59:00.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1223): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-114
11-22 15:59:00.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1223): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-22 15:59:00.251: E/AndroidRuntime(1223):     at com.example.a_talker.MainTalker$sendthr.run(MainTalker.java:89)
11-22 15:59:00.701: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1223): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection*
```

Comment: show that exception for God sake... And add no tags in subject http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: W/dalvikvm(1121): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)

Comment: that is the exception I get after it try to run data = output[i].getBytes(); for the third time.

Comment: Please post the entire stack trace.

Comment: Post the whole exception. All red lines from LogCat view

Comment: Edit your question to add error logs! Don't post them in comments, it just makes it harder to help you. I assume you want help!

Answer (score 0):

You got NPE in line 89. According to my count it's:

```
packet = new DatagramPacket(data,data.length,InetAddress.getByName("192.168.8.17"), 11001);
```

if so, then most likely `data` is `null`. (if line 89 is elsewhere, point which one it is).

Also do not call

```
System.out.println(count);
```

on Android. Do

```
Log.i( TAG, "count: " + count );
```

You got this in multiple places (line 54, 80, 93, 101, 103, 105...), so fix them all

Comment: I was using this only to know where the error happens, it makes it easier to debug the errors.

Comment: `data = output[i].getBytes();` this is where the code stops when I run the debugger.

Comment: then apparently `output[i]` is `null`. Plant `Log.i(TAG, "" + output[i]);` or do step-by-step debugging to find the culprit

Comment: yeah , I've tried to debug it, it appears that output is getting the values like this, but I don't know how to fix the loop `[3, 1: djsfhewnke, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, jriuwhffit, 2: jriuwhffit, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, jroij, 3: jroij, ......`